# How to findOneAndUpdate MongoDB object inside array from multiple arrays inside object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to mongodD. Although i have wrote correct logic to push object inside cardsData bankCardsArray, but i am not able to make logic to edit a card.

**I have following Data in MongoDB, **

```
UserData = {
    "_id":  "63b43ab32fc8d3c100cafecc",
    "name": "Praveen Lohar",
    "email": "pr********@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2b$12$3nwifHakrBu94BwLXAC4Nu16Kw0.xyW8vAIPTMSgY7cYttVklDIZq",
    "loginIdsArray": [
      
        {
        "title": "Airtel App",
        "logoIndex": 3,
        "category": "Finance",
        "app": "Airtel Thanks",
        "username": "p******@gmail.com ",
        "password": "xxxxxxx",
        "isFavourite": false,
        "_id":"63b440ee738a50fc333df3ca"
      }
    ],

    "cardsData": {
      "bankCardsArray": [
        {
          "title": "SBI CC",
          "logoIndex": 72,
          "category": "Bank",
          "cardHolder": "Prsscscs",
          "cardNumber": "524xxxxxxxx20xx",
          "expiry": "23/54",
          "cvv": "00",
          "isFavourite": false,
          "_id": "63b974adb9acaa24a4ebec8b"
           
        },  
        {
            "title": "AXIS CC",
            "logoIndex": 85,
            "category": "Bank",
            "cardHolder": "blsllslss",
            "cardNumber": "524xxxxxxxx20xx",
            "expiry": "23/54",
            "cvv": "00",
            "isFavourite": false,
            "_id": "63b974adb9acaa24a4ebe5f"
             
          }
      ],
      "identityCardsArray": [
        {
          "title": "Aadhar Card",
          "logoIndex": 98,
          "category": "Identity",
          "cardHolder": "Name_1",
          "cardNumber": "54*******455454",
          "issueDate": "2012",
          "dob": "23/05",
          "isFavourite": false,
          "_id":"63b974e6bd0d03c116955f67"
        }
      ],
      "licenseCardsArray": [
        {
          "title": "Two Wheeler License",
          "logoIndex": 0,
          "category": "License",
          "cardHolder": "Klaus Michealson",
          "licenseNumber": "RJ/22/ADL-542/474/01",
          "expiry": "2036",
          "dob": "13/06",
          "isFavourite": false,
          "_id":"63b97535bd0d03c116955f69"
          
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

1. I want to find the user with _id
2. Then for that user i want to got to cardsData object
3. Then in cardsData object i want to got to bankCardsArray
4. Then in bankCardsArray , i want to update fields of a card with particular id

```
Const res = findOneAndUpdate(
{ 'cardsData.bankCardsArray._id':card_id },
{ $set{ 'cardsData.bankCardsArray.$.title': req.body.title });
```

---

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what you've already tried?

Comment: I have edit the code at end

Comment: It looks like you're using the wrong field names? `bankCardsArray` vs `cardsArray`?

Comment: cardsArray is not in use. CardsData key has three arrays bankCardsArray, identityCardsArray, licenseCardsArray which i am concerned about right now

Comment: Right. And the code you say doesn't work doesn't reference any of those fields. It uses 'cardsArray'

Comment: I have re-edit the code. I works now correctly, but how to reference the user with particular email and  then make query inside bankCardsArray

Answer (score -1):

Use "." operator to access nested fields.
Refer these mongodb documentation
[query-array-of-documents](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/)
[query-embedded-documents](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/).
Hope this helps.

Comment: const res await  = UserDataCollection.findOneAndUpdate(
{"cardsData.cardArrays._id" : req.params.id },
{ 
$set:{ 
"cardsData.cardsArray.$.title" : req.body.title, 
 }
})     i did something like this and it worked but what if i want to first find the user with particular email then for that users cardsData i want to edit